# Finding out total number of permutations of a string

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, permutation

I am trying to compute the total number of permutations of a given string with the following program:

**Program**

```
    class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "ABC";
        int n = str.length();

        //System.out.println(permute(str, 0, n-1));
        permute(str, 0, n-1);
    }

    private static int permute(String str, int l, int r){
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        if (l == r)
            //System.out.println(str);
            list.add(str);
        else
        {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                str = swap(str,l,i);
                permute(str, l+1, r);
                str = swap(str,l,i);
            }
        }
        /*for (int i=0;i<list.size() ;i++ ) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }*/
        return list.size();
    } 
public static String swap(String a, int i, int j){
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i] ;
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }
}
```

**Output** : 0

Again I apply the same method for displaying the permutations of the given string. The following program shows my approach :

**Program**

```
    class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String str = "ABC";
        int n = str.length();

        //System.out.println(permute(str, 0, n-1));
        permute(str, 0, n-1);
    }

    private static void permute(String str, int l, int r){
        ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
        if (l == r)
            //System.out.println(str);
            list.add(str);
        else
        {
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
            {
                str = swap(str,l,i);
                permute(str, l+1, r);
                str = swap(str,l,i);
            }
        }
        for (int i=0;i<list.size() ;i++ ) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
        //return list.size();
    } 
public static String swap(String a, int i, int j){
        char temp;
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
        temp = charArray[i] ;
        charArray[i] = charArray[j];
        charArray[j] = temp;
        return String.valueOf(charArray);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB
```

My doubt lies here, when I try to return the size of the `arraylist` I get `0` as my output but the when I print out all the elements of the `list`, it shows all the permutations.

Can anyone clear my doubt?

Comment: It's because you're  creating a new List object in the permute method. Make your list a global variable.

Comment: Are you aware that there is no need in generation of all permutations to get their number?

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @MBo, no I did not know that we can get the numbers of permutations without generating all the permutations. Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: @Pritom Mazumdar, oh, that's ``n!`` :D, where n is the length of your string. Since you stored the permutation I thought you will need those later.

Comment: Can anyone explain me how do I optimise the algo ?

Comment: @Pritom Mazumdar, I edited the answer, you can check it out.

Comment: @Schidu Luca: **n!** is not correct if the string can contain letters more than once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not correct that you are creating a list inside your method. Due to recursion you will obtain an empty list at the end.
The fastest fix you can do now it to pass your `ArrayList` in your method.

```
 private static int permute(String str, int l, int r, ArrayList<String> list){

    if (l == r) {
        list.add(str);
    }
    else {
        for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            str = swap(str,l,i);
            permute(str, l+1, r, list);
            str = swap(str,l,i);
        }
    }
    return list.size();
}
```

and call it like this :

```
    String str = "ABC";
    int n = str.length();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    permute(str, 0, n-1, list);

    System.out.println(list.size());
```

now your output should be `6`.

**EDIT**

If you just need the number of permutation, of course it's `n!`, where `n` is the length of your string.

```
private static long numberOfPermutations(long n) {
    if(n == 1 || n == 0) return 1;

    return (n) * numberOfPermutations(n-1);
}
```

Use it this way:

```
 int i = numberOfPermutations("abc".length());

 System.out.println(i);
```

**UPDATE**

As a suggestion, if the `chars` in the string are repeating, do it by another formula  `n!/ (k1!*k2!*k3!...)` . Implimentation :

```
String string = "ABBCCCD";
String[] split = string.split("");

Map<String, Long> collect = Arrays.stream(split).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));


long result = numberOfPermutations(string.length()) / collect.values().stream().map(Main::numberOfPermutations).reduce(1L, (a, b) -> a *b);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Number of permutation is `n!` for all different chars. If some of them are repeating, then formula is  `n!/ (k1!*k2!*k3!...)` where k[i] is amount of every char kind. For example, for `ABBCCCD` result is `7! / (2!*3!)`

Comment: @MBo, yes you are right, should have asked that. For me, in usual cases a permutation problem involves different chars. I'll edit the answer, thanks